# Link properties between nested classes to have same values when changing the property from the nested/base class

Tags: c#, class, properties, nested, variable-assignment

Suppose this:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public NestedClass_ NestedClass;
    internal class NestedClass_ : BaseClass
    {
        public string MyNestedProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, let's say this:

```
var baseClass = new BaseClass();
baseClass.NestedClass.MyNestedProperty = "Value applied from nested class";
```

Can something be done to apply the same value to `baseClass.MyProperty` when changing `baseClass.NestedClass.MyNestedProperty`?

And what about the oposite case:

```
var baseClass = new BaseClass();
baseClass.MyProperty = "Value applied from base class";
```

Can something be done to apply the same value to `baseClass.NestedClass.MyNestedProperty` when changing `baseClass.MyProperty`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this *insane* code?

Comment: @Bryan Crosby Just to know how much amount of insanity C# is able to do ;). Already there are some interesing insane things like instantiating interfaces... just O: ... amazed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way...

```
class BaseClass
{
    private string _myProperty;

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set
        {
            _nestedClass.MyNestedProperty = value;
            _myProperty = value;
        }
    }

    private NestedClass_ _nestedClass = new NestedClass_();

    private class NestedClass_
    {
        public string MyNestedProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public string MyNestedProperty
    {
        get { return _nestedClass.MyNestedProperty; }
        set
        {
            MyProperty = value;
            _nestedClass.MyNestedProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```